# Request tracker - Including CSS on template

Tags: html, css, rt

I'm trying to change the default template "Resolved in HTML", so that when the user receives the e-mail stating that the ticket has been resolved, a satisfaction survey (linked in the email) be filled.

But I would like this link to the survey be a star rating, where each star represents a parameter of the level of satisfaction for the survey treatment.
To make this star rating, I am using HTML and CSS.

But the template reports an error when I use CSS:

> Could not compile the template of codeblock 'text-decoration: none; color: inherit;': syntax error at line 6 template

Follows the code:

```
Subject: Resolvido: {$Ticket->Subject}

Content-Type: text/html

<style type="text/css">

    a {

        text-decoration: none;

        color: inherit;

    }

    .rating {

      unicode-bidi: bidi-override;

      direction: rtl;

      float: left;

    }

    .rating span {

      display: inline-block;

      position: relative;

      width: 3.0em;

    }

    .rating span:before {

       content: "\2606";

       font-size: 50px;

    }

    .rating span:hover:before,

    .rating span:hover ~ span:before {

       content: "\2605";

       cursor: pointer;

       color: gold;

    }

    .clear {

        clear: both;

    }

</style>

<p>De acordo com nossos registros, o seu pedido foi resolvido. Se você tem qualquer outra questão, por favor, responda a esta mensagem.</p>

<p>Por favor, avalie o atendimento:</p>

<div class="rating">

    <a href="https://www.example.com?param1=x&param2=y&rating=excelente"><span></span></a>

    <a href="https://www.example.com?param1=x&param2=y&rating=bom"><span></span></a>

    [more 3 stars]

</div>

<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
```

Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have declared your template as Perl type.  You then need to escape the braces with a backslash, otherwise Text::Template gets confused.

```
a \{

    text-decoration: none;

    color: inherit;

\}
```